# Grammar from Russian State Exam

Tags: present-perfect

To help my students get ready for RSE in English, I go to the official site of the exam and take some materials from there.

Here's a grammar task that makes my feel at a loss.

The story goes about a seagull that was adopted by a man...

> *He slept in a cat’s basket, from which he acquired a taste for Whiskas. Since then, Mr. Pooh has learned the sound of the fridge door
>   opening.*
>
> *He __________________ **(LEAVE)** the family home, but he can’t resist returning three times a day for his favourite food, announcing his arrival by tapping on the door.*

The answer is Past Simple, that is **LEFT**, but to me there should be Present Perfect. I think so because the actions in the sentence are related to the present.

Would it be relevant to use Present Perfect to underline that eventually the seagull has left the family, but (now) he can't resist visiting the family and (still) sees them for his favourite food?

Comment: _Has left_ would seem perfectly acceptable to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Do you go* there (the official site) everyday? :)

I will tell you why the present perfect is better here.

**Compare:**

He **has left** the family home, but he **can’t resist returning three times a day** for his favourite food, announcing his arrival by tapping on the door. [the speaker is speaking at the present time or in the present]

**To:**

He **left** the family home, but **returned yesterday** for his favourite food, announcing his arrival by tapping on the door. [the speaker is describing two finished events]

The simple past would be definitive in this type of sentence. Since the seagull **continues to return**, the past perfect shows he is no longer living at home but is not showing he left home definitively as the simple past would, for example, on Tuesday, last week, yesterday, at midnight. The point is **not when he left**, the point is he is no longer at home **at the time of speaking**.

Compare those to:

**He left last May** but **has been returning everyday since September**. [it is now December].

There, *he left* is definitive. It is also specific. Phrases like last May require simple past.

Comment: Well, not every day, but whenever I need to help my students with the exam, I go there. Just a fact about my teaching experience:)

Yes, I understand that Past Perfect would be even better, but 'left' is given in the key. Are they mistaken?

Comment: Thta's the present perfect. Past perfect would be _had left_.

Comment: @VladimirNazarenko I think I have answered your question. I wrote past instead of present and have corrected it. In terms of what is called pragmatics, I think they are wrong in formal grammar terms. [The correction I made to your question is that you should have written: To help my students, I go etc. and not: Helping my students, I go.]

Comment: Oh, thanks for clarification:) Being a non-native speaker is not an easy job! I got very confused because of that typo and thought that I had missed something in terms of basic grammar. Now everything is clear! You're very helpful.

Comment: @VladimirNazarenko No worries. Stay safe. :)  Teachers understand each other.